# python nose framework: A plugin to display results in a human friendly format

Tags: python, nose

Any format which is targeted for humans (.html, .doc, whatever) would be good. I cannot find any plugin that provides it
All I found was XUNIT or XML output..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a stand-alone visualization tool, but Hudson can graph your test and coverage results. If there's a failure, it will list the problems on a web page with hyperlinks to each individual test result.

This blog post explains the setup: http://heisel.org/blog/2009/11/21/django-hudson/. There's a screenshot at the bottom that shows what's possible. It's geared toward django, but the idea is applicable to any python app.

A continuous integration server gives you many benefits beyond just graphing your test results. Hudson can automatically checkout your code after a subversion commit, run all your tests, email you if there's a failure, etc..

http://hudson-ci.org/

Answer (score 0):

Nose has an html output module! (the --cover-html option). See here : http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/plugins/cover.html

Answer (score 0):

nosetest provide a way to dump result to xunit-xml format. use options below -

```
   --with-xunit --xunit-file <file.xml>
```

once you have results, you can use xslt to convert your runs to xhtml.
I tried https://github.com/mungayree/nosetest-xunit-xslt

it displays result of your runs.